# Symmetric matrix and inner product: $\langle Ah,x\rangle = \langle h,A^T x\rangle =\langle Ax,h\rangle$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inner-products, symmetric-matrices

If A is real, symmetric, regular, positive definite matrix in $R^{n.n}$ and $x,h\in R^n$, why is it $\langle Ah,x\rangle = \langle h,A^T x\rangle =\langle Ax,h\rangle$?
Is there some rule or theorem for this?

Comment: For the second equality, one has $A=A^T$ by symmetry, and use symmetry of the scalar product. For the first equality, just write out what both sides mean in terms of a double summation. Regular and positive definite are not used.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that inner product can be written as: $\langle x,y\rangle=y^Tx$. So $\langle Ah, x\rangle=x^T Ah$ and $\langle h, A^T x\rangle=(A^Tx)^Th=(x^TA)h=\langle Ah,x\rangle.$ Also $A^T=A$ as $A$ is symmetric and this gives the last equality.

Answer (score 1):

I think this follows straightforward from definitions:

$\,A\,$ is symmetric and real$\;\implies A^*=A^t=A\;$ , so since the inner product is real we get

$$\langle x,y\rangle =\langle y,x\rangle \;\;\text{ and}\;\;\langle y,A^tx\rangle=\langle A^tx,y\rangle=\langle Ax,y\rangle\;\ldots $$